# How to determine which services did not send logs in the last 24h Grafana Loki LogQL

Tags: logging, grafana, grafana-loki, logql

My company has a lot of customers, each having 1 or more services. Each of these services sends logs to a loki server.
Each Service is unique by the combination of the 2 labels customer_id and service_name.
I would like to have a grafana panel that has a table with a list of all services that did not send any logs in the last 24 hours.

I make queries based on the 2 labels customer_id and service_name. I have all possible values stored in variables with the same name on the grafana dashboard.
I tried using the absent_over_time function,

```
absent_over_time({customer_id=~"$customer_id", service_name=~"$service_name"}[24h])
```

but here I have the problem that if one of the combinations of service_name and customer_id returns a stream then the function returns no data.
All help would be apprechiated.

Comment: Prometheus' model is not great for looking something what is missing. And also loki cannot really answer what is missing when you are passing reger for label selector.

Comment: Have you considered using rows and panels repetition based on variables?

Comment: I have tried that but there I have the problem that most customers only have between 1 and 3 diffrent services, but in total there are around 15 services so I would have lots of useless panels

Comment: AFAIK, there is no really good way for this. One rather sustainable way would be to have a list of expected pairs (service, customer) in file fed to grafana, and then comparing it with present logs. Something along the lines ``count_over_time({filename="expected.log", customer_id=~"$customer_id", service_name=~"$service_name"} [1d]) unless on(customer_id, service_name) count_over_time({filename!="expected.log", customer_id=~"$customer_id", service_name=~"$service_name"}[1d])``

Comment: Hi, sry that I did not answer, I had written an answer about a week ago, but must not have submitted it. Since I did not find any real solution to this problem I worked around it by using the up metrik from prometheus, since it was already active on the servers.

Comment: This seems like a wise choice. Please consider providing a proper answer with detailed description what have you done, to help future users who will have same idea/problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find any solution to the problem described in my question, but I found a workaround:
The servers where my services are running were also using Prometheus to send information about the services. Therefore I had the `up` metric of Prometheus available.

What I wanted on my dashboard was a Panel with information on services that did not send any logs in the last 24 hours, but did send logs in the last say 7 days. Since the `up` metric reporting any value worked as a tell of the server not sending other things like logs properly, I made 2 queries, 1 retrieving the last up value over 24 hours and 1 retrieving the last up value over 7 days.

Then I used transformations to merge the results of the 2 queries and group by `agent_hostname` (server_identifier unique per customer) and `customer_id`. Afterwards I filtered the lines to display only those where the 24 hour query did not have any data.

Comment: Just in case all this can be done with one promQL query without transformations: `sum by(agent_hostname, customer_id) (last_over_time(up[7d])) unless on(agent_hostname, customer_id) last_over_time(up[7d])`